# Improving an iterative function in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I often struggle writing iterative functions in scheme: it makes writing recursive procedures much simpler. Here is an example of trying to square items in a list using an iterative procedure:

```
(define square (lambda (x) (* x x)))
(define (square-list items)
  (define result nil) ; set result
  (define (iter items-remaining)
    (if (null? items-remaining)
        result
        (set! result (cons (car items-remaining) (iter (cdr items-remaining))))))
  (iter items))

(square-list '(1 2 3 4 5))
; (4 9 16 25)
```

My main question about this is:

- Is there a way to do this procedure **without** having to first define the `result` before the inner procedure? I was trying to make the iterative procedure have the function prototype of `define (iter items-remaining answer)` but was having a hard time implementing it that way.
- And if not, why isn't that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code does not work; but even when fixed up so that it *does* work, this would not be an idiomatic Scheme solution.

To make the posted code work:

- `nil` must be replaced with `'()`, since Scheme does not represent the empty list with `nil`
- `square` must be called on the `car` of `items-remaining`
- `set!` should modify `result` by adding squared numbers to it, not by trying to add the result of a recursive call. This won't work at all here because `set!` returns unspecified values; but even if it *did* work, this would not be tail-recursive (i.e., this would not be an *iterative* process)
- The value of `result` must be *returned*, and it will have to be reversed first since `result` is really an accumulator

Here is a fixed-up version:

```scheme
(define (square-list-0 items)
  (define result '()) ; set result
  (define (iter items-remaining)
    (cond ((null? items-remaining)
           result)
          (else
           (set! result (cons (square (car items-remaining))
                              result))
           (iter (cdr items-remaining)))))
  (iter items)
  (reverse result))
```

A better solution would not use mutation, and would not need `(define result '())`:

```scheme
(define (square-list-1 xs)
  (define (iter xs acc)
    (if (null? xs)
        (reverse acc)
        (iter (cdr xs) (cons (square (car xs)) acc))))
  (iter xs '()))
```

Here an accumulator, `acc`, is added to the lambda list for the `iter` procedure. As results are calculated, they are consed onto `acc`, which means that at the end of this process the first number in `acc` is based on the last number in `xs`. So, the accumulator is reversed before it is returned.

Another way to do this, and probably a more idiomatic solution, is to use a *named `let`*:

```scheme
(define (square-list-2 xs)
  (let iter ((xs xs)
             (acc '()))
    (if (null? xs)
        (reverse acc)
        (iter (cdr xs) (cons (square (car xs)) acc)))))
```

This is a bit more concise, and it lets you bind arguments to their parameters right at the beginning of the definition of the `iter` procedure.

All three of the above solutions define iterative processes, and all three give the same results:

```
> (square-list-0 '(1 2 3 4 5))
(1 4 9 16 25)
> (square-list-1 '(1 2 3 4 5))
(1 4 9 16 25)
> (square-list-2 '(1 2 3 4 5))
(1 4 9 16 25)
```

Of course, you could just use `map`:

```
> (map square '(1 2 3 4 5))
(1 4 9 16 25)
```

Comment: thanks for this great answer. Btw, I was using #lang sicp at the top.